# How to specify SQL Server instance for TFS Express 2015

Tags: sql-server, tfs-2015

I have SQL Server 2014 Express with three instances installed. I want to install Team Foundation Server Express 2015 and use third instance for it. But there is no way to tell TFS to use this third reserved instance, it always forces itself to first SQL Server instance, where is my production database! Don't tell me that it is not possible to select whatever SQL Server instance you want... I took screenshot of TFS Server Configuration Wizard and you can see there is no way to specify this instance. When you press Configure button, installation starts and first found instance is used.

[image: Server Configuration Wizard]

Comment: It may not be possible to control it during setup. It may be possible to move it afterwards using the command line. Would that be viable for you?

Comment: Either it is possible, or it is not possible during setup. So software engineers at Microsoft are retarded so much, that they force TFS on first found SQL Server instance no matter what runs in it?

Comment: It's definitely possible to control everything when you're setting up full-blown TFS. For the *express* variant they may not have felt it was necessary to give as much control, since they want to get people up and running quickly for a far more limited scenario.

Comment: I don't believe they are really so dull. So what about that command line? Depending on its complexity I will try it or revert back to Git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using TFS for personal use or to evaluate the core features, TFS Express is a good choice. We don't recommend using SQL Server Express for anything but personal or evaluation deployments of TFS.

You can use TFSConfig.exe command to change a new SQL Server Instance:

```
tfsconfig unattend /configure /type:basic /inputs:SqlInstance=server\sqlInstanceName
```

Check this blog for more details: https://lajak.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/tfs2012-express-advanced-configuration-part-1/

Comment: If Express version is meant for evaluating full version, both versions should have same user experience during setup, otherwise users can think that you can not select instance in full version too. Who proposed that Express version will have different setup?!

Comment: @Ondřej - Express *isn't* intended for evaluating the full version. Note that Cece said "core features". You can download and install the full version of TFS if you want to evaluate the "full version" and it will install with a trial license, IIRC.