# I have 2 instances of SQL Server Express installed, but TFS has selected the wrong one. No way to point it to the right one?

Tags: sql-server, tfs, tfs-2015

I've installed TFS Express on my laptop. I already had SQL Server 2016 Express installed. When I run the TFS configuration wizard, I'm getting the following error (The version I am using cannot be upgraded - see screenshot):

[image]

According to this link, I need SQL Server 2012 to run the TFS Express 2015. That's what I did. I tried to configure again. However, when I get to the same step, the wizard has already selected the SQL Server 2016 instance (see screenshot).

[image]

And, there's no way I can tell the Wizard to use the 2012 instance I've just installed.

Anyway to change the targeted SQL Server Express instance?

Thanks for helping

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35147856/how-to-specify-sql-server-instance-for-tfs-express-2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, check the [SQL requirement](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/requirements#sql-server) to see whether you have installed the correct SQL edition.

Then you can use TFSConfig.exe command to change a new SQL Server Instance:

```
tfsconfig unattend /configure /type:basic /inputs:SqlInstance=server\sqlInstanceName
```

Comment: I got an error saying that the sql server express should be of the right service pack. However, I think that it'd work given the right package. I ended up by uninstalling the instance. Now I tried to configure TFS, it;s installing the right version of sql server express.

Answer (score 0):

When installing TFS to a pre-installed SQL instance you need to use the "Advanced" wizard and select the named instance.

Comment: I don't see the advanced Wizard option. I've uninstalled/installed TFS, but I don't see the option. I've installed TFS 2015 Express, Is that an issue?